# Code doesn't work when I am trying to prepare my multilabel dataset for training, test and validation

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, multilabel-classification

I am trying to divide my multilabel dataset into training, test, and validation. I have a csv file that contains all the image id and their corresponding labels. Each image can belong to multiple classes (multilabel image classification).

I want to divide the dataset into training, test, and validation. However, I keep on getting

```
Index Error: index 1034 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

The code is provided below:

```
import argparse
import csv
import os

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm

def save_csv(data, path, fieldnames=['image_path', 'airplane', 'bare_soil', 'buildings', 'cars', 'chaparral', 'court', 'dock', 'field', 'grass', 'mobile_home', 
                                     'pavement', 'sand', 'sea', 'ship', 'tanks', 'trees', 'water']):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, row)))


annotation = 'LandUse_Multilabeled.csv'

all_data = []
with open(annotation) as csv_file:
    # parse it as CSV
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    # tqdm shows pretty progress bar
    # each row in the CSV file corresponds to the image
    for row in tqdm(reader, total=reader.line_num):
        # we need image ID to build the path to the image file
        img_id = row['IMAGE\LABEL']
        # we're going to use only 3 attributes
        airplane = row['airplane']
        bare_soil = row['bare-soil']
        buildings = row['buildings']
        cars = row['cars']
        chaparral = row['chaparral']
        court = row['court']
        dock = row['dock']
        field = row['field']
        grass = row['grass']
        mobile_home = row['mobile-home']
        pavement = row['pavement']
        sand = row['sand']
        sea = row['sea']
        ship = row['ship']
        tanks = row['tanks']
        trees = row['trees']
        water = row['water']
        
        img_name = os.path.join('/notebooks', 'All_Images', str(img_id) + '.tif')
        # check if file is in place
        if os.path.exists(img_name):
            # check if the image has 80*60 pixels with 3 channels
            img = Image.open(img_name)
            if img.size == (60, 80) and img.mode == "RGB":
                all_data.append([img_name, airplane, bare_soil, buildings, cars, chaparral, court, dock, field, grass, mobile_home, pavement,
                                 sand, sea, ship, tanks, trees, water])
                print(all_data)
        else:
            print("Something went wrong: there is no file ", img_name)
            




# set the seed of the random numbers generator, so we can reproduce the results later
np.random.seed(42)
# construct a Numpy array from the list
all_data = np.asarray(all_data)

# Take 40000 samples in random order
inds = np.random.choice(2100, replace=False)
# split the data into train, val, test and save them as csv files
save_csv(all_data[inds][:1470], os.path.join('/notebooks', 'train2.csv'))
save_csv(all_data[inds][1471:1680], os.path.join('/notebooks','val2.csv'))
save_csv(all_data[inds][1681:2100], os.path.join('/notebooks', 'test2.csv'))
```

Comment: I tried splitting at the end. I create a different CSV file and add images randomly into training, test, and validation

Comment: Have you checked that the data is appended as expected?

Comment: When I try to print " all_data", it shows that its empty

Comment: I would do a deepdive on if you get to the append, and if you do what you actually append as that seem to be the problem. You can take the random index in the all_data (as if you wouldn't that give a python list error), and because of that it seems that the parameters that's in the appended list may be the problem.